# Android Custom View inside Linear Layout with other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom view to display a simple piechart.
My intention is to take some values like size,background color etc thru Layout xml file.
I derive the radius of the circle, strokewidth etc as a **factor of the height of the view**(width is equal to width of the parent/screen) and all dimensions are based on this radius.

Here is my layout xml for the fragment

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bluegrey200"
tools:context="ash.dbtest.GraphPieChartFragment">

    <ash.dbtest.GraphPieChartView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pieChart1"
        custom:backgroundColor="@color/bluegrey800"
        custom:labelColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="800px"
        />
```

This appears perfectly fine now.

See the image:

[image]

The **black rectangle** is the area used in the overridden onDraw method.  Note the **blue diagonal line** showing the bounds of the rectangle. 
I know the height is mentioned in pixels and it must be in dp;  but the values are now for debugging purpose.

I changed my layout xml file to below to add a banner above the Custom view in another linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bluegrey200"
tools:context="ash.dbtest.GraphPieChartFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TestBanner"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ash.dbtest.GraphPieChartView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pieChart1"
        custom:backgroundColor="@color/bluegrey800"
        custom:labelColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="800px"
        />
```

See the screenshot now, it goes weird.

See image here:

[image]

Now my customview moves to the bottom, but is getting truncated.  The onDraw method is getting the right dimensions and the circle is getting drawn correctly.  But somehow the View is getting truncated. In the screenshot below, note that the **black rectangle is incomplete** and the **blue diagonal line is getting truncated**. 
What could be the issue ?
I am a beginner around android and hope that I have provided all required information. I did not post the code because its just basic draws on canvas. 
Thank you very much for your time on this.

Code on the GraphPieCharView.onDraw

```
  @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Log.d("onDraw","onDraw");
    Log.d("onDraw1",Float.toString(this.getLeft()));
    Log.d("onDraw2",Float.toString(this.getTop()));
    Log.d("onDraw3",Float.toString(this.getRight()));
    Log.d("onDraw4",Float.toString(this.getBottom()));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(),this.getTop(),this.getRight(),this.getBottom(),paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

because your GraphPieChartView  is below TextView

Comment: the GraphPieChartView is below TextView and that is expected. My question is why is the Rectangle getting truncated. The code gist in my onDraw method is added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
I was drawing the rectangle using the below code 
`canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(),this.getTop(),this.getRight(),this.getBottom(),paint);`

Lets say the page is 1500px high and 1000px wide. 
Here, when the customview is the only view on the page, below are the results of the getters.
left - 0
top - 0
right - 1000
bottom - 800

I drew the rectangle in these bounds, and all the calculation based on these bounds; it worked fine.

Now, when the custom view is the second view when listed vertically, with the top TextView taking say 50px,

left - 0
top - 50
right - 1000
bottom - 850

But these values are relative to the whole screen (1000*1500).
But inside my custom view, the canvas I have is 1000*800, starting from 0,0 and ending at 1000,800 diagonally.
But I was drawing on the canvas as if it starts from 0,50 and ending at 1000,850.

Adjusted the calculation inside the onDraw method to always start from 0,0 and it solved the issue.

Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it will not work on screens with other dimensions (e.g. 480*800). Are you going to publish just for 1000*1500 screens? - you should use 'getMeasured...()' and then adjust the values for 'drawRect()'.